# Symmetry of infinite harmonic oscillators in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, harmonic-oscillator, group-theory

We know that the system (Hamiltonian) of $N$ harmonic oscillators possesses $SU(N)$ symmetry, where
\begin{equation}
H=\hbar \omega \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left( a_{i}^{\dagger } a_{i} +\frac{1}{2}\right) .
\end{equation}
We can see $H$ is invariant under $U(N)$ transformation:
\begin{equation}
Ua_{i}^{\dagger } U^{\dagger } =\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{j}^{\dagger } U_{ji} \ ,
\end{equation}
where $U_{ij} \in U( N)$. Actually, the dynamical group of $H$ is larger $Sp( N,\mathbb{R})$, see [How to show that an $N$-dimensional SHO's dynamics symmetry is $SU(N)$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317659/how-to-show-that-an-n-dimensional-shos-dynamics-symmetry-is-sun).

However, we know that the free part of the Hamiltonian of QFT can be viewed as an infinite harmonic oscillator in momentum space:
\begin{equation}
H_{0} =\int \mathrm{d}^{3} kk^{0}\left( a^{\dagger }(\boldsymbol{k}) a(\boldsymbol{k}) +\frac{1}{2} \delta ^{3} (\boldsymbol{k} -\boldsymbol{k} )\right) \ ,
\end{equation}

where the discrete index $i$ is replaced with continuous momentum $\boldsymbol{k}$. It seems that $H_{0}$ have $U( \infty )$ symmetry (or larger $Sp( \infty ,\mathbb{R})$ symmetry), which seems weird.

So my question is:

1. What's the formal mathematical description of this kind of "infinite" symmetry?
2. Is there any implication of this symmetry in physics? (If exists/non-trivial?)

Comment: Here is a [start](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9tahoe.pdf), and the published refs cited therein. Further [see](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66124/relations-between-diffeomorphism-symmetry-theories-and-invariant-sun-n-righ), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203123/is-there-any-su-infty-gauge-theory-in-quantum-field-theory).

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thank you for the links. These are the algebric structure of $SU(\infty)$ or $Sp(\infty)$, and their usage in large $N$ expansion or string theory. But I don't see how these are related to this problem(especially $H_0$). In the discrete case, e.g. $N=3$, the represention of $Sp(N),SU(N)$ are related, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Example:_3D_isotropic_harmonic_oscillator. So I wonder is there any discussion of the representation of these algebras and are they related to my problem?

Comment: Yes, the  [J Math Phys **31** 1088 (1990)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528788) does that.